# Typescript passing arguments with spread syntax throws 'Expected x arguments, but got x or more.' error (TS2556)

Tags: typescript

I wrote a short example to explain the situation occurred to my code.

I have two functions resembles to following:

```
function sum3(a: number, b: number, c: number): number {
  return a + b + c
}

function plus1(...args: number[]): number[] {
  return args.map(x => x + 1)
}
```

`function sum3`, the first one, needs exact 3 number arguments. e.g. `sum3(1, 2, 3)` returns `6`.

`function plus`, the second one, has no limit on the number of arguments. e.g. `plus1(100, 200)` returns Array of number `[101, 201]`, `plus1(300, 400, 500)` returns `[301, 401, 501]`.

The error happened when I tried to call the function `sum3` with spread syntax.

```
// javascript returns 303
// typescript throws an error: Expected 3 arguments, but got 1 or more. (TS2556)
sum3(101, ...plus1(100, 100))
```

My typescript version is the newest, 4.2.4. Is this a bug?

Comment: `...` isn't an operator, operators can't do what `...` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I actually solved your problem, but I got another error which I cannot solve right now.

This implementation returns a type with the correct number of elements in the tuple, without a need for overloads:

```
function sum3(a: number, b: number, c: number): number {
    return a + b + c;
}

function plus1<T extends Array<number>>(...args: T): [...T] {
    return args.map(x => x + 1); // Target requires 1 element(s) but source may have fewer.
    //  return args.map(x => x + 1) as [...T]; // No error with casting
}

sum3(101, ...plus1(100, 100)); // [100, 100]
sum3(101, ...plus1(100, 100, 100)); // [100, 100, 100], Expected 3 arguments, but got 4.
```

I believe the reason for the error is that Array.map typings don't use variadic tuples, they return arrays instead.

Comment: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWwMwAoCGAuRMdAIwFMAnAGkWIKLTKsQjpIoEpWGLEBvAKERDE5UlBDkkORAGoas5gG5+AX379QkWAkQAHADYhkARgA8AFUSkAHlFJgAJskQBBcuRwBPU-UYA+PywAOhCccgBzZAJzTkQAbRCg8wBdPkFhAHoMkTEJKQjkILQcXSxrRABeP0RyuWN2RUQsxHMw8LEcgEcQGFFnYyt9UjR7KCxkdhoQKBQ4CQhSRGLPRAALHAA3ReBSAHcKIPShUXFJRDbC4tLyqpqFevPnBJCUxuaAOTgrdzhyRF2YFBVswcMhYGBwqp1KhMFhjAAGYzURIGIzGOHw+HUBHw9gNJrZOI47GY5L8GHYBFIxAowwmDFYxDEpmYvGKIA)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a bug. Think about the general case: `plus1` just says it returns `number[]`. That could have zero, one, two, three, four, five, or any other number of elements in it. But `sum3` expects exactly three (one from the other argument, and two from `plus1`).

One solution is a bunch of explicit overloads ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWwMwAoCGAuRMdAIwFMAnAGkWIKLTKsQjpIoEpWGLEBvAKERDE5UlBDkkORAGoas5vwC+-fqEiwEiAA4AbEMgCMuLo2q1Cbcp0QBtemcvdyAXQDca8NHhI9B4-hOjhYOFNQsQRwE9lbUoUzx7p4aPjr6RiaRTCGxzKZhiAAm+dbR8XG55VlJ6t5afhmBVTnO4SXUxVnUpCU2Ma1dg1WJHrWavunGAHQzOOQA5sglti428St8gsKi4pKIc4tTaDjaWAAeiAC8AHyIF3KG7MqqqJhYhgAMhtQzUw3Gnw+1EB7HYbiAA)):

```
function plus1(a: number, b: number): [number, number];
function plus1(a: number, b: number, c: number): [number, number, number];
function plus1(a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number): [number, number, number, number];
function plus1(a: number, b: number, c: number, d: number, e: number): [number, number, number, number, number];
function plus1(...args: number[]): number[] {
    return args.map(x => x + 1)
}
```

Then your call works, because it matches the `function plus1(a: number, b: number): [number, number]` signature. That would work for up to five arguments, after which the overload returning `number[]` would kick in.

Another solution is to use a type assertion on your `plus1` call saying that it returns `[number, number]`, not `number[]` ([playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZxAWwMwAoCGAuRMdAIwFMAnAGkWIKLTKsQjpIoEpWGLEBvAKERDE5UlBDkkORAGoas5vwC+-fqEiwEiAA4AbEMgCMWAHRmc5AObIujANoBdToTblHfQcNHjJiC9ZM0HG0sAA9EAF4APkRwuUN2ZVVUTCxDAAZDajMTLD0DYwz06iL2P2REO3pGamqKJ3YAbiA)):

```
sum3(101, ...(plus1(100, 100) as [number, number]));
```

...but type assertions are best avoided. For example, if you added a third argument to your `plus1` call, the assertion would be incorrect, but TypeScript would have no way of knowing that.

Comment: ok...I understand. thank you for the answer!
...However, my original function (`plus1` in example) is actually for calculating multiple vectors, especially for polygons...so it usually processes over 100 arguments ;)
At least I want to suppress complie errors since there is no problem with the original function. Please let me know if there is a diffrent way to solve this problem. Thank you!